# 2 collectionView in the same ViewController, but only one can perform segue

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, segue

I have two collectionViews in the same viewController, one is horizontal scroll and has the ageLabel and the other is vertically scroll and has the heightLabel, both of them has the same segue name "toNextView" and they go to the same new viewController, the only difference is the new viewController will show age or height.

My problem is: Only one collectionView I can select and jump to new viewController but the other can't select

Comment: So is that an issue you're facing or is that what you want to implement? Also, please show your code of the collection views' data source and delegate methods, especially the `collectionView...didSelect` method.

Comment: you can use 2 segues for each 'collectionView' or set the name of next 'viewController' in 'didSelect' of each 'collectionView' by 'prepare(forSegue...)' method.

Comment: if you have multiple collectionViews and the same object (probably your controller) set as a delegate, you need to the delegate to differentiate between the two - commonly done with two different tags. in each delegate method check the tag and handle appropriately

Comment: Do you have some code associated with this? If so... put it in the question. :-)

Comment: It's unclear if 'collection view...didSelect' is being called for both collection views or only for one.  Can you confirm?     Are you telling the new Viewcontroller which was picked in 'prepare(for segue)'?